function to count maximum number of co-occurring entities for combination of 3.5 million ids?
I have been given this:
x | y
1 | a,b,c,d,e

2 | a,b,c,d

3 | a,c,d
...

I'd like this:
1,2 | 4 (a,b,c,d)

1,3 | 3 (a,c,d)

2,3 | 3 (a,c,d)

I have x -> 3*10^6 such rows (3 million records)
y could be -> between 5 to 200
x can be called number of posts and y can be called entities
Is there a way to determine the result having the maximum count of entites record on the top of the list?

CROSS JOIN is not an option

I've tried running it on spark cluster with 3 vms (20 cores each).

Truncating the size to 20k records (10^8 operations)
This runs for around 3 mins.
give that replica of 20k record to each machine & divide the data to 100 chunks. Pass each chunk to vm and do a join with 20k record to fetch top 100 local.
Update top 100 global accordingly.

20k records: 7 mb , 3.6 million records: 850 mb

Not sure I get your points. Just hard to optimize. Will look at deleted chatgpt text but not convinced.

I couldn't fully understand your question and the example provided. Could you expand on the example with more details and explanations?

Max count of entities with more data. ???

x can be called number of posts and y can be called entities

Can be done but not optimized in any way afaics.

When back from hols will answer.
